# optirun fails in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I am trying to use Nvidia Optimus on my laptop by using Bumblebee, I have an Intel Core i5 with an Nvidia Geforce GT 630M.

I have followed the instructions on the wiki page at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee, but when trying to run optirun with Firefox (or any other program, like glxspheres), I get the following error:

```
[ 1921.452820] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver
[ 1921.452905] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

I have tried googling the issue but I couldn't find any solution that didn't cause more problems.

Thank you for your time.

Here is my bumblebee.conf: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1333324/

Comment: Please update your answer providing the content of your bumblebee config file. This can be done using `cat /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf | pastebinit`, which will give you a link to a webpage with the content of that file.

Comment: I have added a link to my bumblebee.conf. Please check the main post.

Comment: Run optirun and paste the bottom lines of `/var/log/syslog` file. Or try to troubleshoot it yourself, http://wiki.bumblebee-project.org/Troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

Probably your problem is in the configuration of Bumblebee. To configure it you need to edit `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`. To do so, you can run in a terminal, or using Alt+F2

```
gksu gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
```

First, you need to select which driver you want Bumblebee to use: nvidia or nouveau. If you have installed `bumblebee-nvidia` itś better to use nvidia. Replace `Driver=` with

```
Driver=nvidia
```

Also update the two ocorrences of PMMethod with

```
PMMethod=none
```

After rebooting this should make Bumblebee work. If you get a error running `optirun` regarding permissions you must execute the following command, replacing  with your username:

```
sudo usermod -a -G bumblebee <username>
```

This will only let you use your NVidia card (ie it will not make nothing regarding power management). If you want Bumblebee to turn off the NVidia card when it is not used you should check the Wiki link you provided, and the `TurnCardOffAtExit` value in Bumblebee  configuration.

Also, you should install bbswitch-dkms (it requires linux-headers-generic
)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install bbswitch-dkms
```

Comment: Okay, so I changed the Driver= to Driver=nvidia in bumblebee.conf, but now it gives me another error, it says the bumblebee daemon has not been started.

Comment: Have you restarted the system?

Comment: Yes. I have restarted the system.

Comment: ok, then try to run in a terminal the following command: `sudo bumblebeed` and post the output (use http://paste.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: Here is the output of sudo bumblebeed: <http://paste.ubuntu.com/1333439/ >

Comment: I have updated the answer. I think you dont have `bumblebee-nvidia` package installed. Check that it is really installed. If it still dont works try to set `Driver=nouveau`

Comment: I do have the bumblebee-nvidia package installed, and I switched the Driver line to nouveau. It still says the daemon could not be started. I restart every time I make a change to that config.

Comment: Updated. If it still dont starts repeat the step of posting output of `sudo bumblebeed`

Comment: I installed linux-headers-generic, then I did a sudo apt-get install --reinstall on bbswitch-dkms. Now I don't see any errors about bbswitch, but, when I try to optirun anything, I get the same no-driver issue that I put out in my first post. Running bumblebeed says itself is already running in a seperate process.

Comment: Also, this might be unrelated, but I get a 404 when trying to access the ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates ppa.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I have fixed my problem. I followed Salem's instructions and I downloaded the linux-headers-generic package, and then I reinstalled bbswitch-dkms, nvidia-current and nvidia-settings. Now I can use optirun on glxspheres and get 120fps instead of 60fps. Thank-you all.